# Finding a button by it's "tag" in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an android app where initially the user get the "GO" button. On clicking the button a new relative layout is made visible which has a few option buttons namely - "addition" and "subtraction".
I then try to get which button the user has clicked and accordingly present that set of questions. 
However, as soon the the GO button is clicked the app crashes..
My code to check which button in clicked is ---

```
public void start(View view)
    {
        startbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i("YO:", "Start button ok!");
        optionRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        int tag =  (Integer) view.getTag();
        if(tag==4)
            additionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        if(tag==5)
          subtractionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The XML code is

```
<Button
        android:text="Go!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/optionrelativlayout"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:text="Addition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="4  "
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/addition" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/subtraction"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The error is

```
04-24 22:21:39.525 10853-10853/com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer I/YO:: Start button ok!
04-24 22:21:39.527 10853-10853/com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer, PID: 10853
                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.java:177)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
04-24 22:21:39.535 10853-10865/com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer I/ActivityThreadEui: schedulePauseActivity com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer.MainActivity finished=true userLeaving=false configChanges=0 dontReport=false
04-24 22:21:41.098 10853-10853/com.example.rohit_136.brain_trainer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10853 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match anything in your `xml` what is `GO`? Post your stacktrace otherwise we cannot guess where the error is.

Comment: Update the error log!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to use ids that these buttons already have?

```
public void start(View view)
    {
        startbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i("YO:", "Start button ok!");
        optionRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        int id =  view.getId();
        if(id==R.id.addition)
            additionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        if(id==R.id.subtraction)
          subtractionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: but then won't view.getId() get me the Id of the view that i passed to the function. That's not what i want. I want the button that is clicked it's Id.

Answer (score 2):

-- EDIT --

I guess I didn't understand properly what you were trying to achieve.

1 - In your `start()` method, remove this:

```
    int tag =  (Integer) view.getTag();
    if(tag==4)
        additionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    if(tag==5)
      subtractionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
```

2 - Create two new methods and put the visibility lines inside, like that:

```
public void displayAddition(View view){
    additionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
}

public void displaySubtraction(View view){
    subtractionrelativelayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
}
```

3 - In your XML, add them to the buttons:

In `addition` button add the following line:
`android:onClick="displayAddition"`

In `subtraction` button add the following line:
`android:onClick="displaySubtraction"`

Comment: That's not what i aim to do.What i exactly want is something like this--The user clicks on the "GO" button (id-start_button) and then the Go button disappears displaying a new relative layout that has the addition and subtraction button and when the user cliks on those button i want to get that button's tag.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but even 4 years later I had trouble finding helpful answers for your exact question. I have 16 buttons that all call the same method (it's a memory "matching" game), and they need to identify themselves as indexes from 0 - 15 to match an array of corresponding variables. It took a bit of juggling, but I finally figured this out and hope this can help others.

The "tag" attribute on a button or view is actually stored as an *Object* even though you define it with a String value (putting in a 0 for it will not store an Int). It *can* be used to reference a Resource (though it doesn't HAVE to be), so you could set the tag on the button with a Resource name, such as my_button_string, create a String resource by that name, and when calling getTag() it would return the String from the Resource... in a very roundabout way. But if you just assign a raw value to it, such as "0", you can get that 0 returned with getTag(), but again in a very roundabout way. Here's why it's so difficult!

Tag is stored as an Object, so when you call myButton.getTag(), it returns a generic OBJECT type that doesn't like to be cast as an Integer. It doesn't even like to be cast as a String, even though that's how you defined it in the first place! But for your (and my) use case, we wanted an Int to identify our button as an index or maybe an enum case or the like. As an aside here, I also had named my buttons numerically so I could iterate over their names to add their clickListeners or perform other group changes to them, so I'll include that part of it as well, because if you have a lot of buttons all going through a single method and want to simply identify them for a Switch/Case or something, this might help some people out.

My buttons were all named as:

```
button_0
button_1
button_2....
```

with corresponding "tag" values of 0, 1, 2, etc....

And in the OnCreate() method of my MainActivity:

```
//Add clickListener to each button
for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {

    //Get ResourceID of each button by iterating their name Strings using loop index as suffix
    int buttonID = getResources().getIdentifier("button_" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());

    //Get button from the ResourceID returned from its name
    Button btn = findViewById(buttonID);

    //Get String value of the button's tag object value
    String tagString = String.valueOf(btn.getTag());

    //Parse the String value (which is known to be an Integer) to its Integer value
    int btnTag = Integer.parseInt(tagString);

    //Set the button's clickListener to call the onButtonTap method and pass
    //the tag value as its argument, identifying the button to the method
    btn.setOnClickListener(v -> onButtonTap(btnTag));
}
```

...and then my button onTap method receives the tag

```
void onButtonTap(int tag) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Button with tag " + tag + "was tapped!");
}
```

You can see back in the getTag() method that I had to use...

```
 String.valueOf(btn.getTag())
```

...to get the raw value from the return Object. I could NOT just cast it to a String. After getting the String value, it parsed into an Integer just fine. It really surprises me that Java makes such a simple and useful idea as the tag so confusing. I do realize that the fact that the tag can refer to a resource does give it some more built-in functionality, but personally I would never use tags in the way they seem to have intended them, but that's just me. I am used to how they are used in Obj C / Swift, where it's just a simple Int, but again, that's just me. Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void callWhenClick(View view){
  Button btn = (Button) view;
  int myTag = Integer.parseInt(btn.getTag().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

You are using `view.getTag()`, but the problem is the view is not a button variable

use this:

```
Button button = (Button) view;
int Tag = button.getTag();
//Do what ever you wanna do with the tag from here on...
```

Hope this helps